# Has anyone figured out how to deal with "dovecot" email handling on Siteground?

Tags: email, mailserver, siteground

I noticed a post in 2018 about my same issue. I am using siteground with "Localdir" (the other posting used SMTP) because our email blasts are small volumes. The emails go out ok, but the civicrm email reports can't find bounces, and clickthroughs ? A siteground support person spent 2 hours "chatting" online trying to help me, but no success. Siteground uses "dovecot" email and all civicrm emails create folder-level addresses like ".bounces.ignored" and "bounces.processed" with three folders under each - "cur, new, tmp". Not sure how to fix/patch this to work ?
I am using drupal 7.69 with civicrm 5.22.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Localdir". Do you mean mail()? And would be good to link to the related posts (was it one of mine?). I have things working with Siteground now, but need to know more context to respond.

Comment: The LocalDir is a protocol on the edit mail account screen (civicrm/admin/mailSettings?reset=1).  And I found a post from Anna Sidwell May 31 '18 at 15:45.

Comment: Does siteground not let you access dovecot through IMAP? I mean on your inbound mail account screen for bounce processing, choose imap as the protocol and enter the settings for the dovecot mail server? Using localdir in production is unusual - I usually only use it for testing the email processor.

Comment: Where would I set that up? You are indicating to use IMAP instead of Localdir?

Comment: The same place where you set it to localdir. In the inbound mail account screen for bounce processing. Administer - CiviMail - Mail Accounts.

Comment: I will try that - thank you.  It's a bit confusing - the civicrm documentation does not quite explain this.

Comment: I tried IMAP vs. Localdir and got an error that the Username/password was not valid. Changed back to Localdir and the process incoming cron job indicated the folder should not be empty.

Comment: OK found the Anna Sidwell post at https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/25109/email-to-activity-processing-cant-create-subfolders-of-the-inbox. I was confused by your reference to SMTP when you are talking about inbound emails issues. I presume the settings you are referring to are under the menu administer>> CiviMail>>Mail Accounts, where I do find a reference to localdir. But I may have answer!

Answer (score 1):

I presume that you are talking about bulk mailings. I have got this working for small volumes hosted on Siteground. I had a lot of problems originally with subfolders though can't remember the details. My solution was as follows.

**Outbound** use mail() and in Administer>>CiviMail>>Mail Setting, set Mailer Batch Limit to 100 and Mailer Cron Job Limit to 1. With the Send Scheduled Mailings cron job running every half hour this throttles the outbound mail within SiteGround's limits.

**Inbound** i set up an account on GMail to handle the bounces so bounce processing account (Adminster>>CiviMail>>Mail Accounts) was set up using IMAP to GMail and address examplereturn@gmail.com and localpart return+ and email domain of return.example.org. I then forwarded @return.example.org to examplereturn@gmail.com. The GMail account needs some special settings as described in https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/civimail/inbound/#return-channel-google-apps. All rather complicated but nothing else I tried worked.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you Mick - I will try what you've described today. Very creative and I hope I get it all working ok :-)